# Expires in nginx.conf throws error on ubuntu but not on OSX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

My nginx.conf is working on local (OSX) but throwing an error on prod (Ubuntu)

The full file: https://github.com/thomasdane/partywave/blob/master/nginx.conf

But the relevant part is:

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  1w;
    text/css                   1w;
    application/javascript     1w;
    ~image/                    1w;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    expires $expires;
    server_name  http://www.partywave.co/;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

On my mac, that works great and outputs:

```
curl -I localhost/images/hero.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 09:27:51 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 270624
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 09:57:09 GMT
ETag: W/"42120-1570e612108"
Expires: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 09:27:51 GMT
```

However when I run the exact same nginx.conf on production (Ubuntu 14.04) I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "expires" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:46
```

If I delete the $expires code, it works fine on production (without the expires of course).

I've been googling for a while and cannot figure out why. Would love any help.

Comment: Are they different versions of `nginx`?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, and that was the problem in the end. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What version of nginx do you have in ubuntu?
If you have 14.04 with default repo, it is [1.4.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nginx). And expires accepts variables only since [1.7.9](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires).
You can add nginx [official repo](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) and install 1.10 from it. Semi-automatic installation:

```
apt-get install -y lsb-release
LIST="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list"; OS=`lsb_release -si | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`; RELEASE=`lsb_release -sc`; if [ ! -f $LIST ]; then echo -e "deb http://nginx.org/packages/$OS/ $RELEASE nginx\ndeb-src http://nginx.org/packages/$OS/ $RELEASE nginx" > $LIST; else echo "File $LIST exists! Check it."; fi
wget -q -O- http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get remove -y nginx-full nginx-common
apt-get install nginx
```

Comment: This solved it! It seems so obvious now. Thank you very much!